# Passing around a Kerberos (TGT) Ticket Granting Ticket. Is Double-Hop Implementation Secure?

Tags: security, wcf-security, kerberos

Why is it okay to pass Kerberos TGTs around between machines (even across networks)?  Isn't this pretty much passing a private key around (which is highly frowned upon the security world)?

The only protection I've read about so far is that it has a set amount of time for which it is valid.

Please answer in terms of why passing a TGT is okay and passing a private key is not.  Please assume that i understand everything will be transferred via SSL/TLS and that these pieces of sensitive data are encrypted while at rest.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a TGT is like passing a sessionId over a SSL/TLS channel, not passing a private key over open network :). It is secure. TGT contents are encrypted, and read only by intendet recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, clients don't pass TGTs around: TGTs are what clients receive once they've authenticated to the Authentication Service (AS).

When a client wants to connect to a remote server/service, it sends its TGT - as part of a larger request - to the Ticket-Granting Service (TGS), which then hands back a ticket that the remote server/service will be able to decrypt with their own TGT.

So unless you're talking about between clients and the TGS, I don't believe that TGTs are passed between client and server.

Here's some documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hey John,  I am referring to a trust by referral aka Double Hop. http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx

Comment: @funa68 - ah, ok.  You're talking about old-school delegation.  We use constrained delegation which leverages S4U instead of actually passing the TGT.